# Add multiple WINS IP addresses using Command prompt

Tags: cmd, netsh

Good afternoon everyone,

I am completely stumped and have exhausted all the links Master Google has to offer on this question; so it's time to ask the experts.

In short I'm trying to add 3 IP addresses the WINS list using a script. To configure this manually using windows control panel is simple yet time consuming and I wish to avoid this due to the number of PC's that need configuring. I have added an example screenshot of what I am attempting to achieve -IP Addresses are examples. [WINS LIST Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o5Jd.jpg)

I have tried the following batch script but it only adds the last address to the wins list.

```
netsh int ip set winsservers "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.1
netsh int ip set winsservers "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.2
netsh int ip set winsservers "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.3
```

I've tried a variation of this script that I came across that uses an index setting for example:

```
netsh int ip set winsservers "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.1 index=0
netsh int ip set winsservers "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.2 index=1
netsh int ip set winsservers "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.3 index=2
```

However this returns a syntax error.
I have looked for a powershell script to do the same thing but again have come up empty handed in my research.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: I would have expected ot to look more like this: **1.**: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add wins name=Wi-Fi addr=10.0.0.1 index=0```, **2.**: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add wins name=Wi-Fi addr=10.0.0.2 index=1```, **3.**: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add wins name=Wi-Fi addr=10.0.0.3 index=2```. In any case, have you looked at the output from `netsh interface ip /?`, `[ENTER]`ed in a Command Prompt window?

Comment: Bud, the syntax you expected solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, my syntax expectation would have been:

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add wins name=Wi-Fi addr=10.0.0.1 index=0
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add wins name=Wi-Fi addr=10.0.0.2 index=1
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add wins name=Wi-Fi addr=10.0.0.3 index=2
```

To learn more about the `netsh.exe` executable, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the following command examples in a Command Prompt window:

- `netsh /?`
- `netsh interface /?`
- `netsh interface ip /?`